# How can I repeat a switch statement and keep the previous text?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, repeat

I'm trying to make a random number generator of sorts with 7 different number ranges to choose from. I'm trying to make it so that the statement will repeat itself, with the previous numbers staying in place.
Here's my code so far:

`

```
var roll;
var Dice = prompt("The options are the d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, and d100.");

  switch (true) {
    case (Dice == 4):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
    case (Dice == 6):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
    case (Dice == 8):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
    case (Dice == 10):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
    case (Dice == 12):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
    case (Dice == 20):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
    case (Dice == 100):
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      document.write(roll);
      break;
  
  default:
    alert("Just put the number of sides the die has. Example: to roll a d4, input '4'.")
    location.reload();
    break;
  }
```

`
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a novice to Javascript, so if there's some simple solution to this I overlooked, my apologies.

I tried putting it all in a while statement, with an unchanging variable being the requirement. (I believe my exact code was var repeat = 3; while(repeat = 3) {)

Comment: what do you mean with *repeat*?

Comment: After the code finishes, I'd like it to be redoable without the need for reloading the page.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` in code you want to reuse after the page has loaded. It can only be used safely when the page is first loading. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: If i understand your request  correctly, you want your code to be executed infinitely ?

Comment: Is there anything like it, that will write text on the website itself?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferred. Again, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: how do you like to exit the asking loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
var roll,Dice;

while(true){
    Dice = prompt("The options are the d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, and d100.")
    if (["4", "6", "8", "10", "12", "20", "100"].includes(Dice)) break;
    else alert("Just put the number of sides the die has. Example: to roll a d4, input '4'.")
}
while(true){
    roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice) + 1;
    prompt(roll+ " , press enter to reroll")
}
```